# wsix installer (.net) set permissions on installed path

Tags: c#

In my project i have WSIX installer which install app on IIS server.
I have problem because app is run by IIS USER (when hosted on IIS) and i need to add permissions to one of file for this user.
How can i do it using WSIX installer?
I mean, how to get installation path after installation and then call powershell script or program after installation, which will receive path and execute piece of code with using this path? I Have tried this:
[Wix - How to run exe files after installation from installed directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271862/wix-how-to-run-exe-files-after-installation-from-installed-directory)
but i don't know how to get installation path (this is place where i will be store additional program/script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm sorry just read some comment in topic above and it works like a charm

```
<CustomAction Id="EXECUTE_AFTER_FINALIZE"
                  Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
                  Execute="immediate"
                  Impersonate="no"
                  Return="asyncNoWait"
                  ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]PostInstallation.exe" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="EXECUTE_AFTER_FINALIZE" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

of course before that i included .exe and .dll files into installer